# How to make generic method and generic input parameter to accept list<classname>

Tags: c#, .net, image, generics, c#-4.0

```
public interface IMerge
{
   byte[] Process(List<Image> req);
}

public class Merge : IMerge
{
  public byte[] Process ( List<Image> req)
  {
    // processing
  }
}
```

Now the above code is a kind of library used by many people. So dll.

I want to make this interface method as generic input parameter that supports List. How to do that?

My Caller has the following:

```
public class Image 
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public byte[] ImageData { get; set ;}
}
```

Folks, I don't want to refer my business objects project dll onto my Reusable component which is IImage. I am wondering if there is a way to make that IMerge generic so still I will be able to achieve the same above

Comment: I'm confused by this question, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What have you tried, how would you *like* to use it from calling code, and what error/problem do you get?  It's not at all clear what you want

Comment: @DavidG: As the component Merge is reusable, I don't want to hardcode the input parameter to my business object name which is the class "Image" in which case I would end up adding reference to whole business objects project into my reusable component. I am trying to make it generic input parameter in reusable component so still I will be able to call from outside using the above mentioned in my question

Comment: So what would you expect your library code to do if it was passed a `List<string>` for example? It sounds like you really want to be accpeting a `List<IImage>` instead of being generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are wanting this, but I am not sure I completely understand your question

```
public byte[] Process<T>(List<T> req) {
...
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Is there anything else should I do?

Comment: Thank you. You and Tobias answer perfect. But I saw your answer first, so I vote this in few mins as time permits

Comment: How to do foreach (var v in List<T>) ?

Comment: @Learner `foreach(var v in req)`

Comment: I want to basically loop through that and have the ImageBytes read to byte[] ....inside foreach...also the name

Comment: I dont know how to do :(

Answer (score 1):

You can make your interface and its implementation to generic to accept the class that you want to send to like

```
public interface IMerge<T>
{
    byte[] Process(List<T> req);
}

public class Merge<T> : IMerge<T>
{
    public byte[] Process(List<T> req)
    {
        // processing
    }
}
```

And you can use it like,

```
//Create sample List of Image class
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

//Pass above list to generic method in Merge class
var result1 = new Merge<Image>().Process(images);
```

Comment: Thank you; I could understand your statements, but I dont understand your usage. I am layman lol excuse. I give you thumbs up vote for your answer, thank you again for your help

Comment: In an above answer that you accepted: your interface is still for only class `Image`. so how you plan to use only its implementation and that is `Merge` class

Comment: So I dont understand what you say. I have no syntax error in using his code. I kept both in interface and implementation. Excelt that I didn't keep a parameter in class and interface. Why you keep that??

Comment: It doesn't give you any error but in that case your interface it useless because its only for your `Image` class

Comment: interfaceis only for my class lol...i dont wanna make it generic...sorry i dont understand what you say coz I am not that depth in programming...I however dont know how to loop through and read the property of ImageBytes to byte[]

Comment: where is your property `ImageBytes`? I didn't see any property with this name in your `Image` class